# Parallel surface to paraboloid

Tags: calculus, conic-sections

I have the equation for a paraboloid

$z=x^2+y^2$

I need to obtain a parallel surface, Does anyone know what is the procedure to determine it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a normal vector of desired length.

The equation of the surface is
$$g\colon (x,y)\mapsto \bigl(x,y,f(x,y)\bigr),$$
the normal vector is the cross product of the derivatives in respect to $x$ and $y$, namely 
$$n=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\f_x\end{pmatrix}
\times\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\f_y\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}-f_x\\-f_y\\1\end{pmatrix},$$
its length is $\sqrt{f_x^2+f_y^2+1}$.  Now define for any real number $\epsilon$ the $\epsilon$-parallel surface $g_{\epsilon}$ of $g$ by
$$g_{\epsilon}(x,y)=g(x,y)+\epsilon\cdot\frac{n(x,y)}{\|n(x,y)\|}$$

In our case $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$.  The normal vector here is $(-2x,-2y,1)$, its length is $\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}$, hence
$$g_{\epsilon}(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\x^2+y^2\end{pmatrix}
+\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{4x^2+4y^2+1}}
\begin{pmatrix}-2x\\-2y\\1\end{pmatrix}$$
will be the parallel surface in oriented distance $\epsilon$.
[image: epsilon=2]
First picture with $\epsilon=2$, second with $\epsilon=10$, where weird things are going on.
[image]

Comment: in such case the equation for the surface would be z= x^2+y^2 +epsilon/...?

Comment: See my edit, please.

Comment: thanks you, you have parameterized the surface.

Comment: Of course, how else would you derive a parallel surface?

Comment: I think it is not possible to work in Cartesian coordinates this problem.

Comment: Good question hehehe, and if I want to graph this function using the Cartesian system, is there any transformation to do it ?.

Comment: Try “3d parametric plot” of Wolfram Alpha.